# Resources for developing Android apps with databases

Tags: java, android, rest, restful-architecture

I'm looking for some resources on developing Android apps with a connected remote database safely and securely. The idea is to have users log in to a personal profile which can be populated with text data, files and images. The app will also have geolocation, text/video chat and some other features but first things first.

I was reading it is bad practice to connect to a remote database, say MySQL, through an app directly and that something called REST API is the preferred and safe method of communication. Are there any good guides/examples on how to connect to to a remote DB in this fashion? Tips?

I have have some school experience in Java but I'm new to Android development.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions that ask us to "_recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource_" are considered off-topic for this site. See the [help/on-topic] for more information on what kinds of questions are on-topic.

Comment: Oh give me a break, I'm asking specifically about mysql data bases and connecting using rest api. I'm sorry if you don't like the phrasing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried Google's Firebase?

You can learn more here:
https://firebase.google.com

Comment: Thanks this is actually a great resource

Comment: Sure, if this is the best solution for your problem, you can mark it as the best answer.